# How to use python-caldav properly

Tags: python, caldav

I followed the Quickstart guide from https://pythonhosted.org/caldav/, but this error (unknown to google) always shows up. Any ideas?

The stack trace:
[image: Stack trace]

```
client = caldav.DAVClient(url='https://caldav.yandex.ru/', username='username', password='password')
my_principal = client.principal()
calendars = my_principal.calendars()

vcal = """BEGIN:VCALENDAR
    VERSION:2.0
    PRODID:-//Example Corp.//CalDAV Client//EN
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    UID:1234567890
    DTSTAMP:20100510T182145Z
    DTSTART:20100512T170000Z
    DTEND:20100512T180000Z
    SUMMARY:This is an event
    END:VEVENT
    END:VCALENDAR
    """

calendars[0]s.save_event(vcal)
```

Comment: Hello Эйнберт Альштейн and welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't attach links to images in your questions, but rather inline them next time. Also, please replace the image with the stack trace with the actual text of the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen several others having the same issue.  Your `vcal` string above contains leading spaces, which is against the icalendar standard, and the vobject library will reject it.

The error handling in the latest release of the python-caldav library, 0.8.0, has been changed a little bit to give a better indication that the icalendar data may be broken.

You can write it like this, it looks a bit uglier, but it will work:

```py
vcal = """BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Example Corp.//CalDAV Client//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:1234567890
DTSTAMP:20100510T182145Z
DTSTART:20100512T170000Z
DTEND:20100512T180000Z
SUMMARY:This is an event
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
"""
```